# GAP for Design Theory

Tags: group-theory, gap, simple-groups, combinatorial-designs

In journal titled "Unitals, Projective Planes and Other Combinatorial Structures Constructed from the Unitary Groups U(3,q), q=3,4,5,7", in the picture attached, [image]

GAP used there, the word: "Using GAP[11], one can check that ........."

How to code those in GAP? If you know anything (like tutorial in GAP or anything) or the code for those, please inform me, even a little information, really means much to me, thank you.

note: if i ask the source code to the author of journal, is it croos ethic code in knowledge? or if not, will the author give me the source code?

Thank You,

Sincerely,
M. Reza H.

Comment: As for your last question: The journal will likely not have the software. There is nothing wrong in asking the author, and there is a fair chance that they will send you the code they used if it is in good shape, however: a) They might not have kept the code b) They might have worked interactively, never producing written down code c) The code might contain other information they might not want to disclose and cleaning it up for distribution would not be worth the effort. d) It might be incomprehensible to all but the authors.

Comment: thank you for your opinion, now I've known tht it is ok to ask for the code to the author, and for the (a) - (d), I agree with you, it must be something to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in fact not too difficult. Checking the description of the maximal subgroups $H_1$ and $H_5$, it becomes clear that by "unitary group", the author means "projective special unitary group" (as opposed to the other varieties of unitary group). With this information, you can go ahead and just type the following GAP code into the REPL loop.

```
gap> G := PSU(3,5);
<permutation group of size 126000 with 2 generators>
gap> ccl := ConjugacyClassesMaximalSubgroups(G);;
gap> List(ccl, c -> Size(c));
[ 50, 50, 50, 126, 175, 175, 175, 525 ]
```

This lists the sizes of the conjugacy classes of the maximal subgroups of $G$, hinting to the fact that the paper talks about representatives from the fourth and eigth conjugacy class.

```
gap> List(ccl, c -> Size(c[1]));
[ 2520, 2520, 2520, 1000, 720, 720, 720, 240 ]
```

And this definitely confirms that hint, so we select those two conjugacy classes and choose any representatives of them as our groups $H_1$ and $H_5$.

```
gap> Cl1 := ccl[8];;
gap> Cl5 := ccl[4];;
gap> H1 := Cl1[1];
<permutation group of size 240 with 2 generators>
gap> H5 := Cl5[1];
<permutation group of size 1000 with 2 generators>
```

It is sufficient here to select just **one** representative from the conjugacy class of $H_1$ when categorizing and counting intersections:

```
gap> intersections := List(Cl5, c -> Intersection(H1, c));;
```

Next we filter out all those intersections isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and count and describe the remaining ones:

```
gap> largeIntersections := Filtered(intersections, i -> Size(i) <> 2);;
gap> Size(largeIntersections);
6
gap> List(largeIntersections, i -> StructureDescription(i));
[ "C5 : C8", "C5 : C8", "C5 : C8", "C5 : C8", "C5 : C8", "C5 : C8" ]
```

---

***Added on Nov-08-2017:***

Now, we set up our set $\mathcal{S}$ of the $126$ subsets $S_i$ of the conjucacy class of $H_1$ intersecting a given conjugate of $H_5$ in a group of type C5:C8:

```
gap> S := List(Cl5, c5 -> Filtered(Cl1, c1 -> Size(Intersection(c1, c5)) <> 2));;
gap> Size(S);
126
```

And finally, we verify that any two distinct such $S_i$ intersect in a set containing just one element:

```
gap> Comb := Combinations([1..126], 2);;
gap> Filtered(Comb, c -> Size(Intersection(S[c[1]], S[c[2]])) <> 1);
[  ]
```

Again, for an introduction to GAP, I recommend you read the official tutorial and referenc manual which can both be found at http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/manuals.html.

Comment: wow very great answer i need, for the completeness, would you mind to write the code for S_i and to count the intersection S_i and S_j above? But anyway, i'm very glad to see your answer! it helped me a lot! :))) Thank you very much!

Comment: How about it Mr. jpvee?

Comment: @RezaHabibi: I added a few lines (and made some minor changes to the existing ones); hope it helps.